# Any benefits when clustering node.js application server in single core computer

Tags: node.js, processor

This question is meant for single core only therefore multiple cores are out.

I am running Node.js application as HTTP server on single core computer using Express.js. Assuming that my server is able to handle 1000 concurrent requests, would clustering brings about any better in response speed ?

Does process context switch has much impact on performance in this case ?

Comment: There are too many factors to consider to give a confident answer either way. The best thing to do would be to try both approaches and benchmark your results by timing response cycles when artificially flooding the server with requests. Even then, factors like the layout and state of the network your computer is connected on will impact response times, so make sure to isolate your network when you do test.

Comment: Hi, I do understand those factors. My point of view is to determine whether cluster has a certain enhancement towards server like It does in multiple cores. What do you think if we negate all affecting factors, only cluster versus non-cluster ?

Comment: As the answer below says, the only thing you can be sure of is reliability. If one process crashes due to an [exogenous exception](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/), you can rely on the other processes in the cluster to continue handling responses in its absence. There are no guarantees about performance either way, so just benchmark it if it's really that critical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> would clustering brings about any better in response speed ?

You are aware of the fact that in clustered mode, your application will be running behind a load balancer, that will in turn take some CPU and memory to manage and forward the network traffic. Then, what's left of the resources, will be used to distribute the network load.

Apart from a few, rare and easily avoidable cases such as [@Cristyan mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53601301/1762944)—in which case your load balancer can be an orchestrator managing most of the stuff, like Kubernetes—running a Node.js app in cluster does not make sense to me, on a single CPU core. If the process has to wait for an item, it has to wait for it! Asynchronously you can make it work on other requests, but even in this case, other processes would want to take a share of CPU too.

Comment: Single Core != Single Thread. A core can have multiple concurrent processes, but I'm still under the belief that the answer is inconclusive until a benchmark is performed.

Comment: Indeed my server is running behind a load balancer. Despite the incoming requests are equally redirected to all processes by the load balancer, single core schedules each process to run sequentially therefore overall speed is slower if not the same.

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't expect improvements in speed, but you might get some other benefits.

for example if the process crashes, the other nodejs instance could still work.

Comment: I gave you an upvote only since you didn't backup your statement with explanation on why it does not improve speed